# HTML forms are not visible in AMP pages

Tags: html, forms, amp-html

We have a website which is developed using php. And now we want to move our website on AMP pages for mobile users. And we have some static forms but it is not visible in our AMP pages. Complete page is loading except forms.

Any idea how to resolve the issue.

I have followed this [link](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/) for refrence. Please let me know if I have to do something extra.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal can i have link please

Comment: @gauravagarwal still are you facing issue?

Comment: No, we have not used that. We have changed the plan.